# SVModalWebViewController - Pass URL from UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a main UIWebView and I am trying to open any URL using SVWebViewController. My code can be seen bellow.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        SVModalWebViewController *webViewController = [[SVModalWebViewController alloc] initWithAddress:@"http://google.com"];
        [self presentViewController:webViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

It seems like SVWebViewController has an initWithAddress parameter. I want to know if I can pass the requested URL in that parameter.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way out of this. It seems like I could work with

**initWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request**

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        SVModalWebViewController *webViewController = [[SVModalWebViewController alloc] initWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request];
        [self presentViewController:webViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```